# I am trying to use multiple 2 arrays for binding data for svg circles but cannot figure out how

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

Say that I have 2 arrays :

```
    var x_axis_values = [0,1,2,3];

    var y_axis_values = [2,3,4,5];

    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")

                                     .attr("width", 200)

                                     .attr("height", 200);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")

                        .data(x_axis_values)
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle");


var circleAttributes = circles

                        .attr("cx",function(d) {return d;})
```

Here I cannot bind data for "cy" since the array I am using is x_axis_values. How to bind data from y_axis_values array here? I know this could be simpler with JSON format but it would be better if i get this done with arrays.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the index you are at and return the corresponding value from the `y_axis_values` array :

```
var x_axis_values = [0, 1, 2, 3];

var y_axis_values = [2, 3, 4, 5];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")

.data(x_axis_values)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");


var circleAttributes = circles
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) { //add i here to get current index
    return y_axis_values[i]; //gets current index of x_axis_values and  gets the corresponding y_axis_values value
  })
```